# Macbook Pro 15" early 2013 won't turn on anymore

Tags: macbook, macbook-pro, macbook-pro-retina

My Macbook Pro 15", retina display, early 2013 suddenly doesn't turn on anymore. I can hear the boot up sound, but the display doesn't turn on and the Apple Logo doesn't show up.

I thought that the graphics chip could be broken, but it's not only the display that doesn't work. The Caps Lock LED isn't lighting up as well.

It has about 80% charge and the power cable also works. I tried to use an external monitor but it didn't make a difference. I also tried SMC reset and all those things, without success.

Any ideas what the defect could be?

Comment: Can you attach an external display? Does the diagnostic mode work (press D during boot)? If not, most likely the logic board is fried and you'll need to have that replaced.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried this and it didn't work, so I gave the macbook to the apple support.